# How to create a bar chart with Age ranges vs Percentages

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

I am really stumped on how to make a bar chart (shown bellow) with the Age vs Percentage.
[image: goal chart]

This is what I have done so far and I know it's incorrect (Age vs Count).
[image: current chart]

I need guidance on how to create this bar chart.

Current code:

```
# Import the dependancies 
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Load the data from the CSV file
netflix_df = pd.read_csv('./input/Netflix_Userbase.csv')
netflix_df.head()
```

[image: dataset]

```
# Create a bar chart for the user ages
age_group = netflix_df.groupby("Age")
age_count = age_group["Age"].count()
age_chart = age_count.plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) or [qcut](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html) to split the data into age groups?

Let's say, for example, that we have this data frame:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=0)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'age': rng.normal(loc=25, scale=40, size=100),
    'val': np.arange(100)
})
```

To split it into age groups we can use `pandas.cut` like this:

```
age_groups = pd.cut(df['age'], [2, 17, 34, 54, 60])
```

To count and get percentages of each group, we can use `value_counts` with the `normalize=True` parameter:

```
age_groups = age_groups.value_counts(normalize=True, sort=False)
```

This will aggregate data into `Sequence` of percentages with age bins as its index; `sort=False` is set to avoid sorting by value, because what we really need is sorting by index:

```
age_groups = age_groups.sort_index()
```

And the final touch:

```
age_groups.plot(kind='bar')
```

or (to make it look a little better):

```
ax = (100*age_groups).plot(kind='bar')
ax.grid(axis='y', linestyle='--')
ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation = 0)
```

[image: bar plot of age bins]

#### Update

Here is somewhat more elaborated code written to make the bar chart as close to the original as possible.

**Prepare data**

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=0)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    # get ages between 2 and 100 including
    'age': rng.normal(loc=35, scale=20, size=100).round().clip(2,100),
    'some_value': np.arange(100)
})

# by default pd.cut returnes left-opened intervals
# which means the first value in bins should be lower
# of the minimal age (i.e. 1 in this case, where 2 is the lowerst age)
age_bins = [1, 17, 34, 54, 100]
age_groups = (
    pd.cut(df['age'], age_bins)
    .value_counts(normalize=True, sort=False)
    .sort_index()
)
```

**Plot a bar chart**

```py
# plot percentages
ax = (100*age_groups).plot(kind='bar')
# add values above bars 
ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], fmt='%.1f%%');
# replace xticklabels
ax.set_xticklabels(f'{left+1}-{right}' 
                   for left, right in zip(age_bins[:-1], age_bins[1:]))
# set horizontal gridlines
ax.yaxis.grid(True, linestyle='--')
# put griglines below bars
ax.set_axisbelow(True)
# assure that xticklabes are oriented horizontally
ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation = 0)
# remove ticks
ax.tick_params(left=False, bottom=False)
# hide borders
ax.spines[['left','top','right']].set_visible(False)
# save to a file
ax.figure.savefig('age_bar_chart.png')
```

**Output**
[image: final bar chart output]

---

```
python           : 3.11
pandas           : 1.5.1
numpy            : 1.23.4
matplotlib       : 3.6.1
```

Comment: You are an amazing human. Thank you SO much!